# Error Public Key when trying to ssh into Google Cloud Platform VM

Tags: ssh, visual-studio-code, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, vscode-remote

I had been using VSCode's remote-ssh to access my virtual machines running on google cloud. This had been working perfectly fine until I made a snapshot of my most recent instance and created a new instance out of this on a larger VM. Now when  I try to connect (through any method) I get: " Permission denied (publickey).". I have spent countless hours deleting and re-adding, and recreating my ssh keys to no avail. Before I simply ran "gcloud compute config-ssh" and this created a working config file, but now this works. Please help, I have tried everything and there is simply no way for me to ssh. On the website I can click the ssh button to open up their shell, but cannot do it from my terminal

Comment: Are you able to connect to the VM by running this command in the Cloud shell in the GCP console:

- gcloud compute ssh --project [PROJECT_ID] --zone [ZONE] [INSTANCE_NAME]

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance

Answer (score 3):

The problem may be related to the lack of identification of your SSH private key during connection in VSCode. You can indicate your private key adding IdentityFile option pointing to your SSH private key, this in your SSH connection host entries in SSH configuration files:

```
Host vm_name
        HostName external_ip
        IdentityFile /path/to/ssh_private_key
        Port port_number
```

Here the long story if you or someone need more information.

You can go from the start for ensure that you do no have compromise your SSH keys and that is the origin of problem.

**Create SSH Key**

First, create new ssh keys.In the computer that you will use to access your remote host, that is Google VM instance, open your terminal or cmd and go to the ssh folder to generate the keys.

My ssh config and keys are under my user directory, `/home/my_user/.ssh` on Linux or `C:\Users\my_user\.ssh on Windows`.

The I will cd to one of these path, depending on for which of them I using at the moment.

Linux:

```
cd /home/my_user/.ssh
```

Windows:

```
cd C:\Users\my_user\.ssh
```

**Command to generate SSH key**

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -f my_ssh_key -C user
```

**my_ssh_key**: the name your key, you can put what you want to better identify

**user**: must be the user that you want to use to connect at your Google VM instance.

This will generate an Private Key named `my_ssh_key` and a Public key named `my_ssh_key.pub`.

Alternatively, stay in any location of operating system and passing the absolute path where to generate the keys:

Linux:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -f /home/my_user/.ssh/my_ssh_key -C user
```

Windows:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -f C:\Users\my_user\.ssh\my_ssh_key -C user
```

**Copy the public key in your Google cloud VM authorized_keys file**

```
/home/my_user/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

** Do not rewrite anyone public key that already exists jus append in the file of `authorized_keys` file.

**Add new ssh Host entry for remote connection**

Click on `Remote SSH manager`, the icon at the bottom right of the VS Code, click on the `Remote SSH: Open Configuration File` option and choose your ssh configuration file to add another SSH entry for remote connection.

The config file must be under SSH directory, the same path used in the step of generate SSH keys.

Linux:

```
/home/my_user/.ssh/config
```

Windows:

```
C:\Users\my_user\.ssh\config
```

To add another Host, write the following make the properly changes:

```
Host vm_name
    HostName external_ip
    IdentityFile /path/to/ssh_private_key
    Port port_number
```

**vm_name**: is alias to connect with ssh command in practical way, could be what you want.

**external_ip**: the external of your Google VM instance, you can get in the VM instances panel at https://console.cloud.google.com/

**IdentityFile**: the path for yout private SSH key, the file that you generated that note have .pub extension.
Linux:

```
/home/my_user/.ssh/my_ssh_key
```

Windows:

```
C:\Users\my_user\.ssh\my_ssh_key
```

**Port**: the por number of SSH of your Google VM instance, 22 is the default port.

Now it is just choose this host to connect to your Google VM instance.

For more details about SSH settings on Google Cloud Platform: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys#linux-and-macos_1

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed explanation! It really saved my day. Just a small tip for the ones who face issues to connect with VS Code  in Windows: When indicating the path to the IdentityFile, make sure to use apostrophes "". That way, VS Code will understand if the path has folders containing spaces.

Comment: how did you copy without authenticating with the machine first?

Comment: @momo668, to connect in a Google Cloud VM you need at least a direct access with SHH. If you can access the VM trough Google Cloud Console you should be able to edit the authorized_keys and append your SSH public key.

Answer (score -1):

That was beneficial.

Actually, the advised method is to save the private key to
https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/metadata

In this way, it is possible to access all VMs of the project